# How to call the function below

Tags: vb.net, function

I've created a function below (using other post), in which I need to pass the forms class to the function.  However, I can't figure out how to call the function. Any help would be great.

```
Public Function ValidateLaunchForFormShowDialog
    (Of T As {New, Windows.Forms.Form})
    (ByVal pForm As Windows.Forms.Form) As Boolean

End Function
```

Comment: That function doesn't look very useful. Why are you declaring a type parameter constrained to Form then passing a Form instead of a T?

Comment: call like this: Dim test as boolean = ValidateLaunchForFormShowDialg(of frmMain)(frmSecondary) ? But like Blorgbeard said, it's a bit weird to have a type of a windows form

Comment: Thanks!  I have redundant code that is in many different forms.  Instead I wanted to create a class pass the type of form so I can instantiate it dynamically.  Then execute the redundant logic.

Comment: All forms are derived from `Windows.Forms.Form` class. So you can use your function without type argument. `Public Function ValidateLaunchForFormShowDialog(pForm As Windows.Forms.Form) As Boolean`